# Can gradients be applied to lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible in QGIS to apply a gradient to linear features? I'd like for some roads to fade from opaque to transparent as they get further away from some set of points. I can measure the distance to any node on the line and thus for each line could define a start and end distance to base the gradient on.

I've approximated the effect I want by splitting my roads into shorter two-node segments and applying color based on the distance to the second node. The effect however is quite discontinuous and there are many more points where semi-transparent lines overlap slightly than there would be if I was using the original linestrings.

[image: Highways fading with distance from street network]

Is there any way to make this look a bit better?

(Related questions which I hope are outdated now: [Gradient colour for lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157230/gradient-colour-for-lines), [How to visualize measure values along linestrings in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128133/how-to-visualize-measure-values-along-linestrings-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: If you choose a flat cap style instead of square (square is the default), the line segments won't overlap as much.

Answer (score 2):

Using *Geometry Generator* in style, you can change line feature to be rendered as polygon. For example added as small buffer, and later on style that buffer as polygon, so add gradient to it.

[image: gradientline]

Comment: That appears to apply the gradient from the top of the screen to the bottom. If I understand the question correctly, the desired effect is for the line to transition from the first vertex to the last, regardless of the direction of the line.

Comment: Was any solution found for applying gradient to a line depending on the start and end vertexes?