# Visualize road lines in QGIS based on unique features

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, style, color

I have a road network `'TR_ROAD'` with EPSG:4283 crs and 1219 features. The are two type of line line segments grouped with two features "22kV" and "415V" as shown in image 2.

- I am trying to visualize the road segments with two different colors. For example, the lines with "22kV" are with blue color and "415V" with green color.

**What I tried:** Searched for exisiting answers ([1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128133/how-to-visualize-measure-values-along-linestrings-in-qgis/128233#128233), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157230/gradient-colour-for-lines)) but couldn,t found the relevant
solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html

Comment: All you need is a categorised style classified by your baseVoltag field. Then you can edit the colors as you wish for each category. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer

Comment: @BenW. I cant see the classify option here https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJZf.png

Comment: You need to change your symbol type from Single Symbol to Categorized. Then, with the Value combobox select your baseVoltag field. Then click classify.

Comment: You will probably get an extra category called 'all other values' which you can highlight and delete with the red minus button. Then you can double click the little line symbol in each category to change the color.